# Is there any tool to debug the rest calls made by GraphQL Playground?

Tags: graphql

I'm not able to figure out why the REST API call works just fine in Postman but not in the GraphQL Playground. If I could see the actual REST call being made by GraphQL, would be helpful to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[**Firecamp's GraphQL client**](https://github.com/firecampapp/Firecamp) lets you test the GraphQL as an API call or as a Query way.

#### Here is the dedicated GraphQL client

[image]

#### Here is REST like GraphQL client

[image]

> Note: Make sure that you double-check the **method** and **headers** while using REST-like GraphQL client. IN most cases method would be `post` and header should contains `Content-Type: application-json / application/graphql`

Answer (score 0):

The GraphQL playground allows to send GraphQL queries/mutations to your GraphQL server. You can see the requests that are send using the network tab of a browser dev tools.

For example, if a server is in running at the following address http://localhost:4000/graphql, sending a query/mutation, a XHR request will be sent to it. In the **Request Payload** of the **Headers** section there is the query/mutation itself.

In the **Response** section you can see the returned response.

[image]

You can start having a look at the returned response of your query/mutation. Perhaps there is something wrong in the related resolve function in GraphQL.

Comment: Thanks. However, in my case, when I run the same GraphQL query in the Angular client, it works. But the GraphQL playground throws `500 Internal Server Error` in Chrome.